# If matrix $A \in M_{m,n}$ and $n \geq m$, matrix $X \in M_{n,k}$, then when $A X = 0$ (nullspace) is true?

Tags: linear-algebra

Please excuse me asking for the fundamental rank-nullity related problem.

> If matrix $A \in M_{m,n}$ and $n \geq m$, matrix $X \in M_{n,k}$, then when $A X = 0$ (nullspace) is true?

Can this be proved rigorously?

---

My thinking:

At least (necessary? and sufficient condition?) $n$ must be greater than $m$, that is $n > m$ such that $AX=0$. Am I thinking correct? or completely off-the track? But I don't know how to prove it rigorously Thank you so much.

Comment: I think you're off-track. Necessary & sufficient is that each column of $X$ be in the nullspace of $A$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Gerry! However, what are the requirements on the matrix $A$ and also $X$ such that the column of $X$ lie in the $\mathcal{N}(A)$? I hope my question makes sense to you.

Comment: I don't know of any better way of requiring the columns of $X$ to lie in the nullspace of $A$, than to require that the columns of $X$ lie in the nullspace of $A$. I suppose you could say every column of $X$ has to be orthogonal to every row of $A$ – is that any better? What kind of answer are you hoping for?

Comment: I get it now. Thank you very much, Gerry.